# Is there an API for Google Meet?

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, bots, video-streaming

I've been surveyed about Google Meet API.

Specifically whether stream data can be fetched

Does this API exist and support accessing stream data?

If it does exist, please share links to the API's docs.

Comment: "stream data" as in a way to get the actual audio/video data in real time?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no public API (and thus no Google libraries|SDKs) for Google Meet.

A definitive resource for navigating Google's service APIs is [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer). You can verify for yourself that Google Meet is not included.

Unsurprisingly, Google has good search coverage and searches of the form "google meet [api|sdk|library]" return nothing obvious.

Comment: yeah it's so strange... how do companies like fireflies use apis to login to meetings then?